# How to make if-else-sentences by combining info from two different tables

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I have a table of testcases

```
test_table <- data.frame(
  id = c(1:10), 
  result = c('passed:testcase3', 'passed:testcase1', 'failed:testcase3', 
  'failed:testcase2', 'failed:testcase5', 'passed:testcase1', 
  'failed:testcase3', 'failed:testcase5', 'failed:testcase2', 'passed:testcase3')
)
```

And a report that I would like to fill out by matching the information from the test_table

```
report <- data.frame(
  testcase = c('testcase1', 'testcase2', 'testcase3', 'testcase4', 'testcase5'), 
  passed = rep("", 5), failed= rep("", 5)
)
```

I am trying to fill out the number of passed and failed testcases by ifelse-sentences, but I cannot find the right setup.

```
#I create a testcase variable
test_table$testcase <- sub('.+:(.+)', '\\1', test_table$result)

#I try to fill out the missing fields in the report by:

report$passed <- ifelse(test_table$testcase==report$testcase, 
  count(test_table$result '%like%' 'passed')))
report$failed <- ifelse(test_table$testcase==report$testcase,
  count(test_table$result '%like%' 'failed')))
```

The expected result is:

```
report_filled <- data.frame(
  testcase = c('testcase1', 'testcase2', 'testcase3', 'testcase4', 'testcase5'), 
  passed = c('2', '0', '2', '0', '0'), 
  failed = c('0', '2', '2', '0', '2')
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a bit of `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
test_table %>% 
  separate(result, sep=":", into=c("result", "case")) %>% 
  group_by(case) %>% 
  count(result) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=result, values_from=n, values_fill=0)
```

Or alternatively

```
test_table %>% 
  tidyr::separate(result, sep=":", into=c("result", "case")) %>% 
  group_by(case) %>% 
  summarize(passsed=sum(result=="passed"), failed=sum(result=="failed"))
```

Or use base R

```
test_table$testcase <- sub('.+:(.+)', '\\1', test_table$result)
test_table$outcome <- sub('(.+):(.+)', '\\1', test_table$result)

with(test_table, table(testcase, outcome))
```

(note this last option actually returns a table rather than a data.frame)